# storing an object name during construction of another object

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I wanted to create objects from the class “takeSnapshots” that would learn, upon their instantiation, the name of another object from the class “lock” that they could query later as the state of the “lock”  object changes. I can think of multiple ways of letting the object from class “takeSnapshots” know which object it is to query (like including the name of the “lock” object as part of the call to its member functions). But, I thought it better to take care of the relation in the beginning and not worry later if I am calling the correct object combinations.

The included code shows stripped down versions of the two classes and example instantiations created in main. 
I have included the outputs on each line following their respective couts. 
What I expected was that the constructor of “takeSnapshots” would store away the address of the “lock” object. Then I could use it later when taking a snapshot.  You can see that what gets stored away (at least when I use it to get numWheels) is a few addresses off from the address that the “lock” object thinks it has for numWheels.

I am mostly interested in knowing why this code does not work the way I expect, i.e, if this is not a good architectural idea, that is one thing. But with the behavior I’m seeing here, I’m clearly not ready to use pointers in anything complicated and I don’t want to give up on the basic architecture just because of erroneous implementation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// simpleTest.cpp : Demonstrates problem I'm having understanding 
// pointer to an object.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class lock {
public:     //Just while I run a test.
    int numWheels;
    lock(int numW) {
        numWheels = numW;
        cout << " \n In \"lock\" constuctor, address and value of numWheels 
          " << &numWheels << " " << numWheels << endl;
    }   //Values from console: 0034F874 and 4
};


class takeSnapshots {
    lock* localLock;
    public:
    takeSnapshots(lock myLock) {
        localLock = &myLock;
        cout << " \n In \"takeSnapshots\" constuctor, address and value of 
             numWheels " << &localLock->numWheels << " " 
             << localLock->numWheels << endl;
    //Values from console: 0034F794 and 4  "Same value, but not the same 
     //address as expected from "lock."
    }
    void takeASnapSnapshot() {
        cout << " \n When taking a snapshot, address and value of numWheels 
          " << &localLock->numWheels << " " << localLock->numWheels << 
            endl;
    //Values from console: 0034F794 and 2303449     "No longer even the 
    // same value as expected from "lock."
    }
};

int main()
{
    lock yourLock(4);
    takeSnapshots myShots1(yourLock);

    cout << " \n In main (from \"yourLock\"), address and value of 
         numWheels " << &yourLock.numWheels << " " << yourLock.numWheels << 
         endl;
//Values from console: 0034F874 and 4       "Still the same values as set 
//in the constructor of "lock."

//Take a picture
        myShots1.takeASnapSnapshot();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You pass `lock` by value, and take the address of the local variable. As soon as constructor completes, that local variable is destroyed, and the pointer becomes dangling. Pass a pointer (or reference) to `takeSnapshots` constructor instead.

Comment: Prefer passing a reference unless nullptr is a valid input parameter value.   You should still store it as a raw pointer in the class (since it's not an owner), but pass it in as a reference.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. I was focused on the fact that I was keeping the address to the lock object as a member function (and therefore it should persist). But, from your comment, I understand that I was never getting the actual address of the object, just the address of a copy. Everything that I was seeing now makes perfect sense.